# Transform grey60 into rgb | Imagemagick

Tags: javascript, colors, hex, imagemagick, rgb

I'm using Imagemagick in js and I get the color of a pixel with his coordinates like this :

```
im.identify(['-format', '%[pixel:p{' + values.coordinate + '}]', values.file], function(err, color) { 
  console.log('color = ', color);
});
```

It works, but sometimes I get a color like 'grey60' or 'grey40' or something like that.
Is there is a way to request that Imagemagick return data in hex or rgb ? Or there is a way to convert this format into hex or rgb ?

Comment: A feature was added to IM sometime around version 7.0.5 that lets you access the hex value of a pixel. It would look something like this... "%[hex:u.p{W,H}]". It doesn't include the "#" in the output, so if you need that you'll have to construct your string to include it.

Answer (score 1):

In IM 6.9.8-9 and 7.0.5.10, support was added for %[hex:] property similar to %[pixel:], but returning hex values. So this should work in command line mode.

```
convert xc:red -depth 8 -format "%[hex:u.p{0,0}]\n" info:
FF0000
```

or adding the # symbol:

```
convert xc:red -depth 8 -format "\#%[hex:u.p{0,0}]\n" info:
#FF0000
```

For version of IM before that (at least for unix syntax):

```
convert xc:red -depth 8 txt: | tail -n +2 | sed -n 's/^.*\(\#.*\) .*$/\1/p'
#FF0000
```

So if you want a hex color at a coordinate, do something like:

```
convert rose: -depth 8 -format "\#%[hex:u.p{20,20}]\n" info:
#A93B2A
```

or

```
convert rose:[1x1+20+20] txt: | tail -n +2 | sed -n 's/^.*\(\#.*\) .*$/\1/p'
#A93B2A
```